# How can I process the data in my Rest Api?

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

Sorry, if my question is too beginner. So I am creating Rest API.

I have a client:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init( $sUrl );
# Setup request to send json via POST.
$sRequest = json_encode($aRequestData);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
# Print response.
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

And I have the API, where I would like to process the POST data.

How can I see the POST data in the API and after that process? Is there any superglobal variable or anything else?

I tried the $_POST,the $_REQUEST, but not.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: `postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3` is not JSON so why do you claim it is with `Content-Type:application/json`?

Comment: I want sending JSON data, just I forgot this in my example, sorry.

Comment: I would recommend that you got through some basic tutorials about PHP and REST. When sending JSON, you need to send the JSON-data in the body and use the `php://input`-stream to read it. That's a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: And post some of your server side code

Comment: With this: json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))